# Regex cleaning string

Tags: c#, regex, string

I have following string:

`Fox jumps over the rope (1):AB 123`

I'm trying to use Regex in C# to clean this up. I need it like:

`Fox jumps over the rope`.

I'm not able to match this string using regex

```
string badstring = "Fox jumps over the rope (1):AB 123";
string goodstring = Regex.Replace(strIn, @"[^\w\.@-]", "",
                                 RegexOptions.None, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1.5));
```

The string to be removed should match a number inside parentheses and all text after it.

Comment: What is the pattern you are trying to remove? Try `Regex.Replace(badstring, @"\s*\(\d+\).*", "")`

Comment: @Wiktor, this works perfectly. Kindly can you please put this as an answer and explain me more about how did you put that regex together. I'm a bit weak in regex and trying to learn. Thanks.

Comment: Posted [below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53934244/3832970).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
Regex.Replace(badstring, @"\s*\(\d+\).*", "")
```

The `\s*\(\d+\).*` regex matches

- `\s*` - 0+ whitespace chars
- `\(\d+\)` - a `(`, then 1+ digits, `)`
- `.*` - the rest of the line.

The `Regex.Replace` replaces all non-overlapping occurrences with an empty string.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to remove *suffix* (`"(1):AB 123"` in the example) you can try using *Linq* instead of *regular expressions*: with a help of `TakeWhile` we'll obtain all required characters until suffix appears.

```
  using System.Linq;

  ...

  string raw = "Fox jumps over the rope (1):AB 123";

  // "Fox jumps over the rope "
  string cleared = string.Concat(raw
    .TakeWhile(c => char.IsLetter(c) || char.IsWhiteSpace(c)));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    String Pattern = "[^a-zA-Z\\s]+[a-zA-Z]*";
    String StringToClean = "Fox jumps over (1):AB 123 the rope (1):AB 123";
    String StringCleaned = Regex.Replace(StringToClean, @Pattern, "");
    String Cleaned = Regex.Replace(StringCleaned, @"[\s]+", " ");
    Console.WriteLine(Cleaned);
```

> Result = Fox jumps over the rope

Tested on [RegexStorm](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5B%5Ea-zA-Z%5Cs%5D%5Ba-zA-Z%5D*&i=Fox%20jumps%20over%20%281%29%3AAB%20123%20the%20rope%20%281%29%3AAB%20123)
Tested in C# : [Snippet](https://i.ibb.co/f0CbpcR/Capture.png)

Comment: This doesn't work with C#. AB still remains. Output is : `Fox jumps over the rope AB`

Answer (score 0):

```
var s = "Fox jumps over the rope (1):AB 123";
var x = s.Substring(0, s.IndexOf("(") - 1);
// or: var x = s.Split(" (")[0];
```